# Applying Non-Standard Power Assertions & Creating Virtual HIDs

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, hid, iokit

I've got a big ask here, but I am hoping someone might be able to help me. If there's another site you think this should be posted on, please let me know.

I'm the developer of the free app [Amphetamine for macOS](https://apps.apple.com/app/amphetamine/id937984704?mt=12) and I'm hoping to add a new feature to the app - keeping a Mac awake while in [closed-display (clamshell) mode](https://support.apple.com/HT201834) while not having a keyboard/mouse/power adapter/display connected to the Mac. I get requests to add this feature on an almost daily basis.

I've been working on a solution (and it's mostly ready) which uses a non-App Store helper app that must be download and installed separately. I could still go with that solution, but I want to explore one more option before pushing the separate app solution out to the world.

An Amphetamine user tipped me off that another app, [AntiSleep](https://apps.apple.com/app/antisleep-keep-system-awake/id946798523?mt=12) can keep a Mac awake while in closed-display mode, while not meeting [Apple's requirements](https://support.apple.com/HT201834). I've tested this claim, and it's true. After doing a bit of digging into how AntiSleep might be accomplishing this, I've come up with 2 possible theories so far (though there may be more to it):

1. In addition to the [standard power assertion types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iokit/iopmlib_h/iopmassertiontypes?language=objc), it looks like AntiSleep is using (a) private framework(s) to apply non-standard power assertions. The following non-standard power assertion types are active when AntiSleep is keeping a Mac awake: *DenySystemSleep*, *UserIsActive*, *RequiresDisplayAudio*, & *InternalPreventDisplaySleep*. I haven't been able to find much information on these power assertion types beyond what appears in [IOPMLibPrivate.h](https://opensource.apple.com/source/IOKitUser/IOKitUser-1445.71.1/pwr_mgt.subproj/IOPMLibPrivate.h). I'm not familiar at all with using private frameworks, but I assume I could theoretically add the IOPMLibPrivate header file to a project and then create these power assertion types. I understand that would likely result in an App Store review rejection for Amphetamine, of course. What about non-App Store apps? Would Apple notarize an app using this? Beyond that, **could someone help me confirm that the only way to apply these non-standard power assertions is to use a private framework?**
2. I suspect that AntiSleep may also be creating a virtual keyboard and mouse. Certainly, the idea of creating a virtual keyboard and mouse to get around Apple's requirement of having a keyboard and mouse connected to the Mac when using closed-display mode is an intriguing idea. After doing some searching, I found [foohid](https://github.com/unbit/foohid). However, I ran into all kinds of errors trying to add and use the foohid files in a test project. **Would someone be willing to take a look at the [foohid](https://github.com/unbit/foohid) project and help me understand whether it is theoretically possible to include this functionality in an App Store compatible app?** I'm not asking for code help with that (yet). I'd just like some help determining whether it might be possible to do.

Thank you in advance for taking a look.

Comment: After doing some more research, I think the system idle time is being reset programmatically. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52891033/how-to-reset-hididletime-on-macos-10-14.

Comment: ⬆ Scratch that. Seems to not be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would Apple notarize an app using this?

I haven't seen any issues with notarising code that uses private APIs. Currently, Apple only seems to use notarisation for scanning for inclusion of known malware.

> Would someone be willing to take a look at the foohid project and help me understand whether it is theoretically possible to include this functionality in an App Store compatible app?

Taking a quick glance at the code of that project, it's clear it implements a kernel extension (kext). Those are not allowed on the App Store.

However, since macOS 10.15 Catalina, there's a new way to write HID drivers, using [DriverKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/driverkit). The idea is that the APIs are very similar to the kernel APIs, although I suspect it'll be a rewrite of the kext as a DriverKit driver, rather than a simple port.

- DriverKit drivers *are* permitted to be included in App Store apps.
- I **don't** know if a DriverKit based HID driver will solve your specific power management issue.
- If you go with a DriverKit solution, this will only work on 10.15+.

> I suspect that AntiSleep may also be creating a virtual keyboard and mouse.

I haven't looked at AntiSleep, but I do know that in addition to writing an outright HID driver, it's possible to generate HID events using user space APIs such as `IOHIDPostEvent()`. I don't know if those are allowed on the App Store, but as far as I'm aware, IOKitLib is generally fine.

It's possible you might be able to implement your virtual input device using those.

Comment: This is super helpful. Thank you! I don't think DriverKit is the immediate solution here as both AntiSleep and Smart Insomnia (another app that can achieve closed-display sleep w/o meeting Apple's requirements) both run on 10.11+. I can see both apps making an IOConnectCallScalarMethod call. When researching this call, I came across fooHID. I suppose I'll need to keep researching. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer, because I think it sufficiently addresses the questions posed. While I have some additional follow-up questions raised from the answer provided, I think they would be best posed as new questions. Thanks again!